# invalid non-string/buffer chunk Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, chat

I'm studying Node.js in college, and it's my first time learning this kind of programming language. I've got some errors in my attempt to build a chat server. When I try to connect one client to the server, the connection closes immediately and I get the error `Invalid non-string/buffer chunk`. I uploaded a [screenshot](https://plus.google.com/111099475939840728802/posts/dWr7qeeTy1d?pid=6127006472892988946&oid=111099475939840728802&authkey=CNaX15vv_dzj0AE) for you to check out what is wrong, because I've been thinking about it for a while and I can't find any solution.

My Javascript code:

```js
var net = require('net');
var s = require
var sockets = [];
var nombres = [];
var nombresUsados = [];
console.log("Se ha iniciado el sevidor");

var server = net.createServer(function(socket) {
    socket.push(socket);
    nombres.push("Cliente:" + sockets.indexOf(socket));
    nombresUsados.push("Cliente:" + socket.indexOf(socket));

    console.log("Cliente aceptado, nick:" + nombres[sockets.indexOf(socket)]);
    socket.write("Bienvenido" + nombres[sockets.indexOf(socket)] + "\n");

    socket.on('data', function(d) {
        var entrada = d.toString();
        var UsuarioUnico = entrada.match(/^msg/);
        var cambiarNick = entrada.match(/^nick/);
        var quit = entrada.match(/^quit/);
        if (cambiarNick == "nick") {
            var repetido = 0;
            var nombresSinNick = entrada.replace(cambiarNick, '');
            for (var i = nombres.length - 1; i <= 0; i--) {
                if (nombresSinNick.substring(0, nombres[i].toString().length) == nombres[i].toString()) {
                    socket.write("KO, escoja otro nombre\n")
                    repetido = 1;
                }
            };

            if (repetido == 0) {
                nombres[sockets.indexOf(socket)] == nombresSinNick.trim();
                process.on('uncaughtException', function(err) {
                    socket.write("KO\n");
                });

                socket.write("OK. " + nombres[sockets.indexOf(socket)] + "\n");
                console.log(nombresUsados[sockets.indexOf(socket)]) + "su nombre ha sido cambiado por:" + nombres[sockets.indexOf(socket)];
                nombresUsados[sockets.indexOf(socket)] = nombresSinNick.trim();
            }
        } else if (UsuarioUnico = "msg") {
            var nombresSinMsg = entrada.replace(UsuarioUnico, '');
            var encontrado = 0;
            for (var i = nombres.length - 1; i <= 0; i--) {
                if (nombresSinMsg.substring(0, nombres[i].toString().length) == nombres[i].toString()) {
                    var mensaje = nombresSinMsg.replace(nombres[i], '');
                }
            };
            socket.on('end', function() { // CALLBACK: desconexión de cliente
                if (quit == 'quit') {
                    var i = nombres[sockets.indexOf(socket)];
                    sockets.splice(i, 1);
                    console.log("Ha salido el usuario:" + nombres[sockets.indexOf(socket)]);
                }
            });
        }
    });
});

server.listen(9000);
```

Comment: Screenshot link is dead. @Pablo please remove or update.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the problem is the line `socket.push(socket)`. Probably you mean `sockets.push(socket)`. What you're doing now, is attempting to push the socket instance into the socket stream which fails because, as the error says, it's not a string or buffer.

Comment: Hi @PabloMateos if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.